# SVG is there a way to combine multiple lines into a single path

Tags: svg, path, fill, snap.svg

I have an app where I draw multiple lines and arcs as single elements, is there a way to make a copy of these elements into a single path?  For example, if I draw a rectangle using 4 lines, can I make a copy of the 4 sides into a single path so that I can fill the path?

[image: Block changing width]

Here is an example of a block changing widths, going from 4 columns to 3 columns to 2 columns to 1 column.  When initially added it is at 4 columns, each side has a unique class and id and also the top and top and bottom lines have 4 unique classes and id's each. So when I go from 4 to 3 I just hide certain classes and sane goes for going down to 2 or 1.

[image: Another block example]

Here is another example of a differently shaped block.

Comment: Create a path element using the co-ordinates of the rectangle to for it's M and L arguments.

Comment: Well my app is done expect for being able to fill in block, the blocks change width at any time so I was hoping to use existing line/arc elements.  A rectangle is just one simple shape I have. I have MANY different blocks or varying shapes and sizes all of which can change width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your path definitions are next to each other in the svg, you can group them with a g and then use a filter on the group to "fill" the content. I don't know snap, so can't say if it lets you insert arbitrary elements in the rendered svg.

Here's how you would write a filter like that. It uses fat strokes and a green-screen technique to selectively color the areas of overlapping strokes (the inside of the shape) and zero out the areas of non-overlapping strokes (the outside of the shape). This is performance intensive. The right way is to re-write your path code :(

```html
<svg width="800px" height="600px" viewbox="0 0 800 600">
  <defs>
    <filter id="fillme" x="-50%" y="-50%" height="200%" width="200%">
      <feComponentTransfer>
        <feFuncA type="table" tableValues="0 0 0 1 1 1"/>
      </feComponentTransfer>
    </filter>
  </defs>
<g filter="url(#fillme)">
  <path stroke="black" stroke-opacity="0.4" stroke-width="80" fill="none" d="M200,200 a170,170 0 0 1 170,170"/>
  <path stroke="blue"  fill="none" d="M200,200 l0,40"/>
  <path stroke="red" stroke-opacity="0.4" stroke-width="80"fill="none" d="M200 240 a130,130 0 0 1 130,130"/>
  <path stroke="green" fill="none" d="M330,370 l40,0"/>
<g>
  
  
</svg>
```

Comment: It does not look like I can fill a group with Snap SVG. I could put a rectangle inside he group and fill it but not all of the blocks are rectangles like the example image.  Some of them are 1/4 circles or 1/2 circles.  So that would not just fill inside the lines but the entire rectangle that a 1/4 or 1/2 circle takes up.

Comment: Then I do not know of anyway to achieve what you want. You can fill a path and you can fill a shape, but you cannot fill groups of disconnected paths. Sorry to say, but your best bet is to rewrite with complete closed paths.

Comment: I guess I will have to figure out a way to programmatically calculate the outside path when the blocks change in width.  Since I have the data to generate these blocks in an XML file I guess I will have to write some code to build the outside path and then fill in that path.  Was really hoping to avoid having to do that. :(

Comment: I added a sample filter to the question. Note that you have to know the dimension of your shape in order to use the correct stroke width, and this only works for shapes where all lines are parallel. So, probably not so useful?

Comment: I think this might work since all the lines are parallel and since I have data that generates the shapes I know what the dimensions are.  So I think in theory this could work.